# Error: "The extended property value is inconsistent with its type" when saving an appointment

Tags: exchangewebservices, mapi

I'm trying to create an appointment in which I am setting some extended properties. This snippet...

```
$ResponseStatus = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
  [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DefaultExtendedPropertySet]::Appointment,
  0x8218,
  [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer
)

$meeting.SetExtendedProperty($ResponseStatus, 1)
$meeting.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvitationsMode]::SendToNone)
```

...yields this error:

```
Line |
 149 |    $meeting.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvitationsM …
     |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "The extended property value is inconsistent with its
     | type."
```

The error implies a data type issue, but I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly. I'm setting other properties just fine, but those are of types [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Boolean, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String, and [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary. If I comment out this property, the meeting is saved successfully.

Comment: So you are setting ResponseStatus to olResponseOrganized. What is the old value? Can you set that property in MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage)?

Comment: This is a new appointment object I am trying to create, so there is no old value. Are there certain properties that can only be edited after creation? I am able to set it via OutlookSpy afterward, but I haven't tested it in code yet.

Comment: I tried setting the property via Update() after creation, but I get the same error.

Comment: I never tried to set that property through EWS, but you can certainly try to set it in OutlookSpy. But EWS (which has business logic implemented on the protocol level) can be picky when you access MAPI properties that are exposed explicitly, such as MeetingStatus in your case.